# How to use tensorboard debugger with pytorch?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, pytorch, tensorboard

I know pytorch starts to support tensorboard since the version 1.11. But I am wondering is it possible for us to use the debugger plugin for tensorboard with pytorch? I didn't find any information about this. If pytorch can also support tensorboard debugger, it would be extremely convenient and could save us a lot of time.

Comment: Brilliant question, extremely convenient would be an understatement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not and to doubt it ever will be possible. The plugin heavily relies on how TensorFlow internally represents graph nodes which is quite different in PyTorch.